# Can you control Liquibase updateSQL output by major release?

Tags: liquibase

We use liquibase to generate database changes but need these scripted into SQL files because our DB server has neither Liquibase nor even a JVM installed.

We use the updateSQL command to create the DDL script needed to make changes, however if we run (on our development server) a 'dropAll' first we get a change set for every release.

Is there a way to run Liquibase regular 'update' for one collection of changesets (i.e. all prior releases) and then produce updateSQL output only for the last release?  Essentially can we parameterize our build process to indicate the release we are targeting and automatically produce only SQL for that release?

Thanks

Comment: With liquibase 3.1, an easier approach to your dropAll command to clear a database just so you can generate updateSql is to use "offline" mode. http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/offline.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to run a portion of your changelog.

If you break up your changelog files using versions (changelog-1.0.xml, changelog-1.1.xml, changelog-2.0.xml) and then have a master changelog.xml that <include>'s them, then the easiest solution for you may be to just run updateSql passing in the changelog version you want. If you want to generate sql for the entire database, run `liquibase --changelogFile=master.changelog.xml updateSql`.  If you want to generate sql for just version 2.1, run `liquibase --changeLogFile=changelog-2.1.xml updateSql`

@Jens answer works well and is what I often suggest. It has the advantage compared to the above option of catching new changeSets that were introduced into old changelog versions through a merged in patch release, for example.

Beyond that, you could use [context](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html) or [preconditions](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html) to dynamically control what is ran. Depending on your setup there may be ways to get those to work well for you.

Finally, there is always the [extension system](http://liquibase.org/extensions) where you can write custom logic around how changelogs are parsed and executed to pull out older version changeSets based on file name or some other mechanism that works for you.

Answer (score 4):

We have a similar setup.

The way we handle this is we have an "integration" db that always keeps the last official release.

When we have a new release candidate we let liquibase run (updateSQL) against that integration DB. Since it is on the last (resp. the current) release, updateSQL will only write out the difference between the new release candidate and the last release.

So you have a delta ddl that needs to be applied to go from release x to y.

Once the release candidate is released we let liquibase also update the integration db.