# grails: how to use the database migration plugin on a remote production database

Tags: grails, liquibase

If you are using the grails database migration plugin, there are two ways to get your database updated, either by running:

$ grails [environment] dbm-update

Or adding this to the DataSource:

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.reports.updateOnStart = true
```

However, the former requires the ability to connect to the target DB, and the latter is usually deemed unacceptable for production (DB updates are usually done separately during downtime in a controlled manner with backups etc)

Our production databases are in the customers data-center, and we have no access to them. We currently give them a war file they drop into their environment.

We could give them the entire source code, tell them to install Grails 2.5.0, tell them to edit the DataSource.groovy to point to their DB, go into the app dir and type `grails prod dbm-update` but this is not really an option.

Is there any other way?  We could tell them to install liquibase, but the groovy DSL would not be supported (we could probably migrate to the XML version), and just create a tar of the liquibase files.  Is this the only option?

=== update ===

The main reason we can't go with

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true
```

is because it is global - it cannot be set per environment.  Our developers know nothing about SQL and the gotchas around adding columns with no default for example (and it's not possible to add a mysql default constraint of "" in grails for example), so they develop using `dbCreate="update"` as normal. When it comes time to do a build for Testing, the DBA/Dev lead produces the liquibase change log.  This can be applied to the text env using dbm-update, but this wont work for the 30 or so production database we have no access to.

The suggestion to generate updateSQL is not a bad idea - we will look into this.  In production, customers might have copies of the system with many different versions, so we would presumably need to keep a copy of each version.

Comment: If you use the second method your migrations are included in the WAR. If you use external configurations your dev ops team has a configuration/property file/environment variable to configure the datasource and they don't need to edit anything, and the migrations run on application startup when the new WAR is published to the application server. What's wrong with that?

Comment: What would be an ideal solution? If "DB updates are usually done separately during downtime..." then maybe the best thing to do would be to ship a war file with migrations that is the 'admin' side of the app - they drop that WAR file in and then there is some UI to trigger the Liquibase update. After the DB update is done, the admin war file could possibly even deploy the new application war file.

Comment: You could use the `updateSQL` command to generate files instead of letting liquibase do the upate directy on the database. This is how we do it. We have an extra (data-emtpy) "integration" database which only purpose is to keep the current state of development for the database. Checkout my answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21476577/332248) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28283918/332248) for further details.